# The width of div tags

Tags: css, html

Im very new to this HTML and CSS stuff, I'm usually fairly good at learning things but this is just hugely infuriating!!!

I basically have a logo, and 3 text links. I want the logo to the left, and the three links on the right next to the logo.

I don't understand how to get these elements t sit next to each other. I have the logo in a DIV and the 3 text links in a DIV. I'v set the width of the logo DIV in CSS, but the text DIV still sits underneath the height of the logo DIV, which is spanning the full width of the page, despite me setting a width for it.

I know that I need to either shorten the width of the DIV (which I'v tried, but I'v either done it wrong, or its not possible), or allow the 2 DIV sections to overlap, but that seems stilly and I thought DIV is a block element, and can't be overlayed.

HELP PLEASE!!!

The code I got is below if it helps:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<title>Josh Shaw Design</title>
</head>

<body id="content">
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
<div>
<a class="nav last" href="about.html">PROJECTS</a>
<a class="nav" href="about.html">CONTACT</a>
<a class="nav" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#content { background-image:url(../images/background-01.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
background-position:top, center
}

#wrapper {margin:auto; width:960px;}


.logo {background-image:url(../images/logo-01.png); height:91px; width:369px;}
.logo:hover { background-image:url(../images/logo2-01.png);height:91px; width:369px;}

@font-face {font-family: quicksand; src:url(../Quicksand-Regular.otf);}

.nav { padding-top:100px; padding-right:20PX; float:right; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; font-family:quicksand; font-size:16px;}
.nav:hover {color:#999;}

.last {padding-right:0px}
```

Comment: Having a block-level element (`<div>`) inside an inline element (`<a>`) is invalid HTML.

Comment: Then how do I link my logo to a webpage, retaining the hover effects I have applied to it?

Comment: I thought answers on here were quick? It's dead simple I know it is, but I'm stupid, please help someone?

Comment: @Niet [HTML5 allows block level elements inside `<a>` tags](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links), which is a welcome feature

Comment: @user3504531 Answers take as long as they take. Never expect users who answer your questions for free and without any obligation to do so to answer on _your_ schedule

Comment: Sorry, I just expected if someone is going to point out my errors, then they could at least reply with an answer/help soon after. It was directed at that first person who answered in honesty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://awesomescreenshot.com/05a2lyg2ef

If that's what you want.

Follows the changes below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<title>Josh Shaw Design</title>
<style>
#content { background-image:url(../images/background-01.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
background-position:top, center
}

#wrapper {margin:auto; width:960px;}


.logo {background-image:url(../images/logo-01.png); height:91px; width:369px;/*I have your picture, I will use color*/ background:#000;}
.logo:hover { background-image:url(../images/logo2-01.png);height:91px; width:369px;}

@font-face {font-family: quicksand; src:url(../Quicksand-Regular.otf);}

.nav { padding-top:100px; padding-right:20PX; float:right; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; font-family:quicksand; font-size:16px;}
.nav:hover {color:#999;}

.last {padding-right:0px}

/*My extra codes*/
a.logo{display:block; float:left;}
div.nav-content{float:left;}
a.nav{padding:0 20px 0 0;/*top right bottom left*/}
</style>
</head>

<body id="content">
<div id="wrapper">
<a class="logo" href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
<div class="nav-content">
<a class="nav last" href="about.html">PROJECTS</a>
<a class="nav" href="about.html">CONTACT</a>
<a class="nav" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- remove floats-->


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish I could understand this haha. So eveything you put under 'my extra codes' I should add? The example you gave is too complex, I don't know what I'm looking at, I'm literally a beginer, I started like 2 days ago haha. Thanks for your attempted help though

Comment: Copy this code that passed, glue in a html page, if you need to add WHAT WHAT I changed

Answer (score 0):

I would change the div around your navigation links to `<nav>`. I would change the name of your class names as well to something like "navList" and change your css to reflect, . Like this.

```
<nav>
<a href="about.html" class="navList">PROJECTS</a>
<a href="about.html" class="navList">CONTACT</a>
<a href="about.html" class="navList">ABOUT</a>
</nav>
```

Then for your logo use `float: left;` and use `float: right;` on your nav, removed the `float: right;` because this will be taken care of with your nav.

```
.logo {
    background-image:url(../images/logo-01.png); 
    height:91px; 
    width:369px;
    float: left;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

.navList {
 padding-top:100px; 
 padding-right:20PX; 
 color:#FFF; 
 text-decoration:none; 
 font-family:quicksand;  
 font-size:16px;
 }
```